# Can't dismiss navigation controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

So I have a simple navigation controller with a sign up, hit done and you go to the home page. The problem is when you go to the home page, the navigation controller follows.

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the last picture (home page), the navigation bar remains. When the user presses "Done" on the first image I use `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginTrue", sender: nil)`
 to go to the "home page". I've tried using

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

But nothing seems to happen. So to wrap it all up, any idea on how I can "dismiss" the navigation controller from the "home page"? Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Try

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

**Update: Swift 4.2**

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a `ViewController` only for the LoginView. Then use `self.dismiss` with `PerformSegue` to reach the `NavigationController`.

Answer (score 1):

Is a signup view controller being presented Modally? Then, on sign up view controller, you could do

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//hide the navigation bar on this page
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}
```

This will hide the navigation bar on your home page, but make sure you use viewWillAppear so whenever you come back to a page the navigation will not reappear.