# How to dismiss a navigation controller presented from another navigation controller in iOS 10 and below?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios10, dismiss, presentviewcontroller

I'm presenting a `UINavigationController` from another `UINavigationController` like this:

```
let customNavigationController = CustomNavigationController()
customNavigationController.viewControllers = [myController]
customNavigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom

self.navigationController.present(customNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then, when a "close" button tapped, I try to dismiss it like this:

```
navigationController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

That works on `iOS 11`, but it is not working neither in `iOS 9` nor `iOS 10`. What I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31127779

Comment: @TahaAmini Thanks, but there is not a selected answer there and it seems that the user who asks has pushed a view controller into a navigation controller. In my scenaro I'm presenting another navigation controller.